# why the update function return int where it must return string?

Tags: html, django, sql-update

i have a django website where it include an update function where the user is allow to edit data.

the update is done and the data in the database is changed but the problem is that the system crash.

and when i tried to print the result of the query  the system return **int where it should return string**

and it display the error below :

> dbEntry.save() #to save into DB AttributeError: 'int' object has no
>   attribute 'save'

## views.py

```
def update(request,pk):
    #deny anonymouse user to enter the  create page
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("login")
    else:
        dbEntry = suspect.objects.get(pk =pk)
        print( "db entry : ",dbEntry)



        if request.method == 'POST': 
            first_name = request.POST['fname']
            print("first_name : ", first_name)
            dbEntry = suspect.objects.filter(pk = pk).update(suspect_name = first_name)
            print( "db entry after update: ",dbEntry)
            dbEntry.save() #to save into DB

    return render(request,'blog/update.html', {"dbEntry":dbEntry})
```

## update.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}


<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/linesAnimation.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/input-lineBorderBlue.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/dropDown.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/home.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/meta-Input.css' %}">
    <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'%}"></script>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="lines">
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  </div>
    <form  method  = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <div id='left-column-Input' class="formInput" include="select()"> 
        <div class="forminputs">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" autocomplete="off" required />
        <label for="fname" class="label-name">
            <span class="content-name" name="fname">{{dbEntry.suspect_name}}</span>
        </label></div>
<div class="home-Button">
    <button id="save" name="save" type="submit">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs,

> The update() method is applied instantly and returns the number of rows matched by the query (which may not be equal to the number of rows updated if some rows already have the new value.

Here you are applying the update command on the queryset, which would update the matched rows and return num of affected rows. Since you're trying to update only one row then you could do like,

```
dbEntry = suspect.objects.filter(pk = pk).first()
if dbEntry:
    dbEntry.suspect_name = first_name
    dbEntry.save()
    print( "db entry after update: ",dbEntry)
else:
    raise Http404('Id not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

simply remove this line: `dbEntry.save()`

because `dbEntry = suspect.objects.filter(pk = pk).update(suspect_name = first_name)` update database and `.save()` dose not need any more

Comment: thank you this was the error but what @Avinash Raj suggest is what i want.